# Is there a name for this tree traversal?

Tags: trees, compilers, parsers

This came when I was looking at block scoping in compiler design.

```
{   A   { B }   { C {D} {E} }   }
```

For the above pseudo code, the order in which the scope varies as we scan left to right is A B A C D C E C A, where A to E represent scopes.

A parse tree can be constructed for the above pseudo code:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

Is their a term for such a traversal order, which for the above tree is A B A C D C E C A?

Comment: [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)?

Comment: [Pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order)?

Comment: @LukeMathieson not pre-order. Main difference is, what we normally call traversal do not represent a tree vertex more than once within the output string.

Comment: @billiska: but nothing stops you from doing more than one action during a DFS. In this case, there are pre-, in- and post-order actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a binary tree that is triple order; each node is visited three times in pre- in- and post-order.  [Knuth](https://books.google.com/books?id=x9AsAwAAQBAJ&lpg=RA6-PA59&ots=B_-_McNa6I&dq=%22triple%20order%22%20tree%20algorithm&pg=RA6-PA59#v=onepage&q=%22triple%20order%22%20tree%20algorithm&f=false) cites it from a paper by Lindstrom and Dwyer; it can be done without a stack by updating the tree in place.

Comment: I think "triple order" would be more applicable to a binary tree than an n-ary tree.

Comment: Correct, I had assumed it was binary.  I'm updating the answer to clarify.

Comment: Interestingly, I think the stackless algorithm can work on an n-ary tree; it works by shifting the child list left and  appending a back-link to the parent, so n children is OK.  But that's a different question.